# How to pass special characters in a parameter for URL

Tags: url, reporting-services, special-characters

Here is an example parameter value I' m trying to pass:

```
ABC_DE:1-5KSP7TRP:New year, SEO, ++ Solids
```

I've tried to encode the special values with this code:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Fields!ID.Value.ToString(),"&","%2526"),"+","%2B"),"-","%2D"),",","%2C"),":","%3A")
```

I've tried removing the ToString(), but that didn't seem to help. Do I also have to encode the spaces as well? The symbols I've replaced so far are &, +,-, ,, and :. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about all the special characters - [System.Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) already does the heavy lifting for you. Add `System.Web` to your project references and then use

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(URLStringToEncode)
```